# curl failing with --insecure(-k) and missing --cacert

Tags: ssl, curl, tls1.3

I have a client server interface.
The case is unusual, because the server authenticates client and not vice versa.

The client sends client cert to the server. The server authenticates the client cert with its root ca cert. There is also an intermediate cert being used, but I don't need that on server to authenticate the client.

The commands go as follows.

`"curl -k --cert client-cert.pem --key client-key.pem https://server.com:443/endpoint"` **(FAIL)**

But if I pass the intermediate cacert as argument to curl, its successful.

`"curl -k --cert client-cert.pem --key client-key.pem --cacert intermediates.pem https://server.com:443/endpoint"`  **(PASS)**

Even if I pass in the root ca(same between client and server) it fails.

`"curl -k --cert client-cert.pem --key client-key.pem --cacert root-ca.pem https://server.com:443/endpoint"`  **(FAIL)**

PS:
**(FAIL)** means, Server says authentication failure!

My Question is:

1. Why should a server care about the --cacert option at all. curl shouldn't be sending over the ca cert regardless. Correct?
2. Why do things work when I only pass intermediates file.

Thanks in advance for the response.

PS:
The client-cert.pem is signed by intermediate ca and intermediate ca is signed by root ca.

Comment: May you clarify which certificates have been signed by the intermediate authority?

Comment: I went ahead and updated my message. 
The client-cert is signed by intermediate ca and intermediate ca is signed by root ca.

Comment: **Yes the client MUST send the chain cert(s)**, but need not include the root, see https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8446#page-65 (your root CA is the anchor). _IF_ your version of curl is built to use OpenSSL (not all are, check `curl -V` or your system's package manager) then OpenSSL uses the truststore set by --cacert to fill in chain cert(s) for the _client_ cert as well as the documented purpose of validating the _server_ cert chain (which you ignored with `-k`). But this is not programming or development.

Comment: having the same issue, any helpful information ?